# Kotlin Serialization: How to serialize MutableStateFlow<Float>?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code

```
@Serializeable
class Car {
   val speed = MutableStateFlow<Int>(0)
   var isMoving: Boolean = false
}
```

The question is how to serialize MutableStateFlow?

Comment: How you want it to be serialized? Do you want to serialize only the current value of state flow?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь yes. value is what needs to be serialized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a specialized serializer for `MutableStateFlow<Int>`.

Either based on generic serializer suggested by @Tenfour04

```
object MutableStateFlowOfIntsSerializer :
    KSerializer<MutableStateFlow<Int>> by MutableStateFlowSerializer(Int.serializer())

class MutableStateFlowSerializer<T>(private val dataSerializer: KSerializer<T>) : KSerializer<MutableStateFlow<T>> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = dataSerializer.descriptor
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: MutableStateFlow<T>) = dataSerializer.serialize(encoder, value.value)
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder) = MutableStateFlow(dataSerializer.deserialize(decoder))
}
```

or from scratch:

```
object MutableStateFlowOfIntsSerializer : KSerializer<MutableStateFlow<Int>> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = Int.serializer().descriptor
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: MutableStateFlow<Int>) =
        Int.serializer().serialize(encoder, value.value)

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder) = MutableStateFlow(Int.serializer().deserialize(decoder))
}
```

and wire it to the `speed` field:

```
@Serializable
class Car {
    @Serializable(with = MutableStateFlowOfIntsSerializer::class)
    val speed = MutableStateFlow(0)
    var isMoving: Boolean = false
}
```

Note, that this serialization approach will serialize `speed` field regardless of `encodeDefaults = false` setting

Answer (score 2):

[Create a custom serializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#custom-serializers-for-a-generic-type) for MutableStateFlow:

```
class MutableStateFlowSerializer<T>(private val dataSerializer: KSerializer<T>) : KSerializer<MutableStateFlow<T>> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = dataSerializer.descriptor
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: MutableStateFlow<T>) = dataSerializer.serialize(encoder, value.value)
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder) = MutableStateFlow(dataSerializer.deserialize(decoder))
}
```

Mark the specific property to use that serializer:

```
@Serializeable
class Car {
   @Serializeable(with = MutableStateFlowSerializer::class)
   val speed = MutableStateFlow<Int>(0)
   var isMoving: Boolean = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I receive compilation error: 
error: incompatible types: Class<MutableStateFlowSerializer> cannot be converted to Class<? extends KSerializer<?>>