# Error: Incompatible types: Class cannot be converted to Class<? extends KSerializer<?>>

Tags: kotlin, serialization, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlinx.serialization

I am using kotinx.serialization library And Getting This error everywhere I specified a custom serializer using @Serializable annotation !

Error :

```
error: incompatible types: Class<MutableStateSerializer> cannot be converted to Class<? extends KSerializer<?>>
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable(with = com.wakaztahir.timeline.utils.serializers.MutableStateSerializer.class)
```

Use :

```
@Serializable(with = MutableStateSerializer::class)
var items = mutableStateOf(listOf<ListItem>())
```

Serializer :

```
class MutableStateSerializer<T>(private val dataSerializer: KSerializer<T>) : KSerializer<MutableState<T>> {
override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = dataSerializer.descriptor

override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: MutableState<T>) =
    dataSerializer.serialize(encoder, value.value)

override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): MutableState<T> =
    mutableStateOf(dataSerializer.deserialize(decoder))

}
```

Comment: MutableState is an interface !

Comment: But there are other classes which aren't , still getting the same error

Comment: Here's the java code where the error occurs

    @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable(with = com.wakaztahir.timeline.utils.serializers.MutableStateSerializer.class)
    @java.lang.Deprecated()
    public static void getText$annotations() {
    }

Comment: var items is inside a class !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin Serialization: How to serialize MutableStateFlow<Float>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68019188/kotlin-serialization-how-to-serialize-mutablestateflowfloat)

Comment: No , it's actually bug with kotlin-kapt , created an issue for it in kotlinx.serialization

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1579